# Unable to resolve within recursive promise function

Tags: node.js, promise, spotify

I think I am fundamentally misunderstanding how Promises work in Node.

I'm writing a very small Express app that I want to return a JSON of all of my Spotify playlists that contain a certain keyword. I am using `spotify-web-api-node` from npm.

Spotify's API limits 50 playlists per request. I had (what I thought to be) a solution: simply increment the offset value until you no longer need to.

My functions looks like this (`playlists` is declared above the route function) :

```
app.get('/playlists', function(req, res) {
    addPlaylistsToList()
        .then((data) => res.json(data))
});

function addPlaylistsToList(offset) {
    if (!offset) { offset = 0; }
    var limit = 50;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists(config.USER, { limit: limit, offset: offset })
            .then(function(data) {
                playlists.push(data.body.items.filter((playlist) => playlist.name.includes(config.TITLE_CONDITION)));
                if (data.body.items.length == limit) {
                    addPlaylistsToList(offset + limit);
                } else {
                    let result = [...new Set(playlists)];
                    resolve(result);
                }
            })
    });
}
```

Am I unable to call `resolve` here? I mean, I know I can't because I get caught in an infinite loop. Is there a "best practice" re: recursive promises? Am I misusing `then`?

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error or it just wont work

Comment: The issue is resolved below, but in its broken state (above), the program hangs upon receiving a request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally fine to use recursive promises, but there's a few things you're missing in your implementation. Each call to `addPlaylistsToList()` creates a new promise, but only one call will create a new promise that actually resolves: the very last one. All the other created promises will be pending infinitely.

You can rewrite the function in a more typical recursive style, something like this:

```
function addPlaylistsToList(offset = 0) { //default parameter value to 0
    var limit = 50;
    return spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists(config.USER, { limit: limit, offset: offset })
        .then(function(data) {
            playlists.push(data.body.items.filter((playlist) => playlist.name.includes(config.TITLE_CONDITION)));
            if (data.body.items.length == limit) {
                return addPlaylistsToList(offset + limit); //return a promise
            } else {
                return [...new Set(playlists)]; //return the final value
            }
        });
}
```

(untested)

This works because returning a promise to the `.then()` callback causes the `.then()` to "follow" the returned promise - it will only resolve when *that* promise resolves, and so on. You can recursively chain promises like this, and ultimately the bottommost one will resolve with your result array, causing all the other ones to resolve with that array as well.

Also, this can be written much cleaner using async/await:

```
async function addPlaylistsToList(offset = 0) { //default parameter value to 0
    var limit = 50;
    var data = await spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists(config.USER, { limit: limit, offset: offset });
    playlists.push(data.body.items.filter((playlist) => playlist.name.includes(config.TITLE_CONDITION)));
    if (data.body.items.length == limit) {
        return await addPlaylistsToList(offset + limit);
    } else {
        return [...new Set(playlists)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This makes a ton of sense, the 'following' of returned promises keeps everything together and doesn't cause this sort of limbo I created. Thank you so much!